# Can you use 802.11u networks to trigger isExpensive mode in iOS13?

Tags: iphone, wifi, 802.1x

Could someone tell me if they have been able to get an iPhone to go into the isExpensive mode when its connected to an 802.11u network?  My goal is to have a network that when a iOS13+ device connects to it the iPhone goes into a mode where background iCloud traffic is restricted.

I've connected to another iPhone in Personal Hotspot mode network and observed that both isExpensive and isConstrained are set to True and Low Data Mode is ON but the end user can still override this. I would like to find a way to get this to work for an 802.11u network where the user could not override it.